# Removing hosts from VCenter permanently without access to VCenter?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I have 3 VMWare hosts. I have root access to VSphere on each of the hosts.  There is a small computer in the office that runs VCenter to which all the hosts are connected. I do not know the login to that machine.

I have removed the hosts from VCenter using the "Unregister this host from VCenter" option in VSphere, but I get a warning that when it is rebooted it may add itself back.

My question is, if I just wipe the VCenter PC after removing all the hosts, will I have any negative consequences?

Comment: `My question is, if I just wipe the VCenter PC after removing all the hosts, will I have any negative consequences?` - Probably not... unless you're using features that require vCenter Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need vCenter anymore and you've removed them then you can go ahead and wipe the vCenter PC.  The warning has to do with vCenter attempting to re-manage the host, but if you take away vCenter it can't do that.